# Encoding Issue(4 byte japanese characters)

Tags: java

I am trying for getting Character for given position for japanese String.I am getting

"`?"`
  instead of Character specially for 4 byte.

Below is the code snippet I am trying to execute.

```
 String jp="";
```

I am trying to print the first character in this String by

```
jp.charAt(0)




ouput="?"
```

please advise for suitable solution.

we have tried with the `UTF-8` encoding.

Answer (score 5):

Java cannot represent those characters as `char`, as they require 2 UTF-16 units to represent. `charAt` here gives you only the first half, which alone is not meaningful. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16.

You can do something like this:

```
import java.lang.Character;

...

    public static String stringAt( String str, int index )
    {
        int codePoint = Character.codePointAt(str, index);
        return new String( Character.toChars(codePoint));
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
         String jp="";


         System.out.println(stringAt(jp, 0)); //Prints 

    }

...
```

To loop through the characters, you would do:

```
    String jp="";
    int len = jp.length();
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        String character = stringAt(jp, i);

        i += ( character.length() -1 );
        System.out.println( character );
    }
    //
    //
    //
    //
```

Note that:

> The Java 2 platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and
>   in the String and StringBuffer classes.

So the input might as well be UTF-8, but it doesn't change the internal representation and the problems that come with it. Only UTF-32 is a truly fixed width encoding where one char can truly represent any unicode character alone.

Edit:

Substring example (this gets tedious, you probably want to find a library for this):

```
public static String substring( String str, int start, int end) {
    int codePointIndex = 0,
        len = str.length();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    //There's no random access in variable width encoding, so
    //loop must be used
    for( int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        String character = stringAt(str, i);
        if( codePointIndex >= start ) {
            sb.append(character);
        }
        if( codePointIndex >= end -1 ) {
            break;
        }
        i += (character.length() - 1);
        codePointIndex++;

    }

    return sb.toString();

}

    String jp = "asdf";
    System.out.println(substring(jp, 0,8)); // asdf
    System.out.println(substring(jp, 0,4)); //as
    System.out.println(substring(jp, 7,8)); //
```

Comment: Hi Esailija thanks for your post.The problem is also coming for substring can you please advise me.

Comment: @Srinu yes, I'll add example of substring.

Comment: Hi Esailija the post for stringAt() is not working if i give String value String jp = "abcv" and i am trying to get the stringAt(jp,2) the output is "?".can you please advise me.

Comment: @Nani you can't use `stringAt` for random access, see my second example to iterate over all characters.